# Has Data's cat Spot always been played by the same cat?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In Star Trek : TNG, the android Data has a cat named Spot. Spot appears in several episodes in multiple seasons. Has this role always been played by the same cat? Or have there been other 'Spots'?

Answer (score 1):

Spot was played by at least six different cats over the seven seasons and movies where Spot makes an appearance.

Spot actually changes from a long-haired Somali cat to an orange tabby in Season 6. Even Spot's gender changes from male to female in the course of the series.

In universe, it's possible Data simply owned multiple cats, all named Spot, although this is never confirmed. Otherwise, the changes to Spot are simple retcons.

According to the [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spot) article on Spot, the six different cats that portrayed Spot include:

1. Two long-haired Somail cats.
2. Monster
3. Brandi
4. Bud
5. Tyler

Additionally, two backup cats, Spencer and Zoe, were also trained to act as Spot for the TNG films.

Comment: Spot II in Discovery seems to imply Spot I in TNG was a single cat (at least in-universe).